# Creating the class stereotype element instance and serializing and de-serializing it

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

In EA We want to create the class stereotype element for 20 diagram with different names.So instead of creating the same instance of class stereotype element for 20 diagram using Add-new method API provided by EA .Is there any way that we can create once the class stereotype element and serialize  and keep it in the serialized file and can it be De-serialized  and used  for remaining  19 diagrams within the same eap file or within the other eap file.

Comment: The title talks about instances, but the question is about stereotypes. I don't understand that.

Comment: I too miss some details to understand what you are asking exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You can export a package to XMI, edit that manually and reimport it to the same project or to a different one, but honestly it's a lot simpler just to use the API. The XMI format is undocumented and every entity in the exported model (class, operation, attribute...) has its own unique identity which you'd need to create for the duplicates.